# Separate a shopping list into multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a shopping list data like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:5, item = c("apple2milk5", "milk1", "juice3apple5", "egg10juice1", "egg8milk2"), stringsAsFactors = F)

#   id         item
# 1  1  apple2milk5
# 2  2        milk1
# 3  3 juice3apple5
# 4  4  egg10juice1
# 5  5    egg8milk2
```

I want to separate the variable `item` into multiple columns and record the number behind the goods. The problem I met is that the goods each person purchases are different so I cannot solve it using `tidyr::separate()` or other analogous functions. What I expect is:

```
#   id apple milk  juice egg  
# 1  1 2     5     NA    NA   
# 2  2 NA    1     NA    NA   
# 3  3 5     NA    3     NA   
# 4  4 NA    NA    1     10   
# 5  5 NA    2     NA    8
```

Note: The categories of goods in the market are unknown. So don't assume there are only 4 kinds of goods.

Thanks for any helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll add yet another answer. It only slightly differs from @ASuliman's but uses a bit of the newer `tidyr` and some cute regex to become a bit more straightforward.

The regex trick is that the pattern `"(?<=\\d)\\B(?=[a-z])"` will match the non-boundary (i.e. an empty location) between numbers and letters, allowing you to create rows for every `"apple5"` type of entry. Extract the letters into an item column and numbers into a count column. Using the new `pivot_wider` which replaces `spread`, you can convert those counts to numeric values as you reshape.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate_rows(item, sep = "(?<=\\d)\\B(?=[a-z])") %>%
  extract(item, into = c("item", "count"), regex = "^([a-z]+)(\\d+)$") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = item, values_from = count, values_fn = list(count = as.numeric))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>      id apple  milk juice   egg
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2     5    NA    NA
#> 2     2    NA     1    NA    NA
#> 3     3     5    NA     3    NA
#> 4     4    NA    NA     1    10
#> 5     5    NA     2    NA     8
```

Answer (score 3):

I just came up with a `tidyverse` solution which uses `stringr::str_extract_all()` to extract the quantities, sets their names as product names, and expands them to wide using `tidyr::unnest_wider()`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(N = map2(str_extract_all(item, "\\d+"), str_extract_all(item, "\\D+"), set_names)) %>%
  unnest_wider(N, transform = as.numeric)

# # A tibble: 5 × 6
#      id item         apple  milk juice   egg
#   <int> <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1 apple2milk5      2     5    NA    NA
# 2     2 milk1           NA     1    NA    NA
# 3     3 juice3apple5     5    NA     3    NA
# 4     4 egg10juice1     NA    NA     1    10
# 5     5 egg8milk2       NA     2    NA     8
```

Answer (score 2):

Possibily something like this, and should work with any item/quantity. 
It just assumes that the quantity follows the item.

Lets use a custom function which extracts item and quantity:

```
my_fun <- function(w) {
  items <- stringr::str_split(w, "\\d+", simplify = T)
  items <- items[items!=""] # dont now why but you get en empty spot each time
  quantities <- stringr::str_split(w, "\\D+", simplify = T)
  quantities <- quantities[quantities!=""]

  d <- data.frame(item = items, quantity=quantities, stringsAsFactors = F)


  return(d)

}
```

Example:

```
my_fun("apple2milk5")
# gives:
#    item quantity
# 1 apple        2
# 2  milk        5
```

Now we can apply the function to each id, using `nest` and `map`:

```
library(dplyr)
df_result <- df %>% 
  nest(item) %>% 
  mutate(res = purrr::map(data, ~my_fun(.x))) %>% 
  unnest(res)

df_results
# # A tibble: 9 x 3
# id item  quantity
# <int> <chr> <chr>   
# 1     1 apple 2       
# 2     1 milk  5       
# 3     2 milk  1       
# 4     3 juice 3       
# 5     3 apple 5       
# 6     4 egg   10      
# 7     4 juice 1       
# 8     5 egg   8       
# 9     5 milk  2
```

Now we can use `dcast()` (probabily `spread` would work too):

```
data.table::dcast(df_result, id~item, value.var="quantity")

#     id apple  egg juice milk
#   1  1     2 <NA>  <NA>    5
#   2  2  <NA> <NA>  <NA>    1
#   3  3     5 <NA>     3 <NA>
#   4  4  <NA>   10     1 <NA>
#   5  5  <NA>    8  <NA>    2
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:5, item = c("apple2milk5", "milk1", "juice3apple5", "egg10juice1", "egg8milk2"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: My thoughts exactly! Alternative to dcast: `tidyr::spread(df, item, quantity)`

Answer (score 2):

```
tmp = lapply(strsplit(df$item, "(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)|(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)", perl = TRUE),
             function(x) {
                 d = split(x, 0:1)
                 setNames(as.numeric(d[[2]]), d[[1]])
             })
nm = unique(unlist(lapply(tmp, names)))

cbind(df, do.call(rbind, lapply(tmp, function(x) setNames(x[nm], nm))))
#  id         item apple milk juice egg
#1  1  apple2milk5     2    5    NA  NA
#2  2        milk1    NA    1    NA  NA
#3  3 juice3apple5     5   NA     3  NA
#4  4  egg10juice1    NA   NA     1  10
#5  5    egg8milk2    NA    2    NA   8
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It's a nice solution.

Answer (score 2):

Place a space before each numeric substring and a newline after it.  Then read that data using `read.table` and `unnest it`.  Finally use `pivot_wider` to convert from long to wide form.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(item = gsub("(\\d+)", " \\1\n", item)) %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(item = list(read.table(text = item, as.is = TRUE))) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  unnest(item) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "V1", values_from = "V2")
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
     id apple  milk juice   egg
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     2     5    NA    NA
2     2    NA     1    NA    NA
3     3     5    NA     3    NA
4     4    NA    NA     1    10
5     5    NA     2    NA     8
```

### Variation

This is a variation of the above code that eliminates the `unnest`.  We replace each numeric string by a space, that string, another space, the `id` and a newline.  Then use `read.table` to read that in.  Note the use of `%$%` rather than `%>%` before the `read.table`.  Finally use `pivot_wider` to convert from long to wide form.

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(item = gsub("(\\d+)", paste(" \\1", id, "\n"), item)) %$%
  read.table(text = item, as.is = TRUE, col.names = c("nm", "no", "id")) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "nm", values_from = "no")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It's a nice solution.

Comment: Hey, `ungroup` in the second last line of the variation part could be removed, right?

Comment: It would  still work but it is really better to always complete a `group_by` or `rowwise` with `ungroup` since otherwise the data will remember it is grouped in subsequent operations and you could be in for a surprise.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple solution in base R and `stringr`:

```
goods <- unique(unlist(stringr::str_split(df$item, pattern = "[0-9]")))
goods <- goods[goods != ""]
df <- cbind(df$id, sapply(goods,
       function(x) stringr::str_extract(df$item, pattern = paste0(x,"[0-9]*"))))
df <- as.data.frame(df)
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], function(x) as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(x, pattern = "[0-9]*$")))
names(df)[1] <- "id"
```

**Output**

```
id apple milk juice egg
1  1     2    5    NA  NA
2  2    NA    1    NA  NA
3  3     5   NA     3  NA
4  4    NA   NA     1   10
5  5    NA    2    NA   8
```

Comment: Sorry, but actually I don't know how many categories of goods in the market. So the first line of your code doesn't work in my case.

Comment: @DarrenTsai fixed

Comment: Thanks for your help. I find that the 4th row shows 1 egg, but it needs to be 10.

Comment: @DarrenTsai fixed one of the patterns. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringi)
df %>% 
  mutate(item2 =gsub("[0-9]", " ", df$item)) %>% 
  mutate(item3 =gsub("[a-z]", " ", df$item)) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(item2, item3), ~stringi::stri_extract_all_words(.) %>% map(paste, collapse=",")) %>% 
  separate_rows(item2, item3, sep = ",") %>% 
  spread(item2, item3)
  id         item apple  egg juice milk
1  1  apple2milk5     2 <NA>  <NA>    5
2  2        milk1  <NA> <NA>  <NA>    1
3  3 juice3apple5     5 <NA>     3 <NA>
4  4  egg10juice1  <NA>   10     1 <NA>
5  5    egg8milk2  <NA>    8  <NA>    2
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It's a nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
#replace any digit followed by a character "positive look-ahead assertion" by the digit plus a comma
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% mutate(item=gsub('(\\d+(?=\\D))','\\1,' ,item, perl = TRUE)) %>% 
       separate_rows(item, sep = ",") %>% 
       extract(item, into = c('prod','quan'), '(\\D+)(\\d+)') %>% 
       spread(prod, quan, fill=0)

  id apple egg juice milk
1  1     2   0     0    5
2  2     0   0     0    1
3  3     5   0     3    0
4  4     0  10     1    0
5  5     0   8     0    2
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It's a nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly base R with some input from `stringr` and `data.table`:

```
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
cbind(
  id = df$id,
  rbindlist(
    lapply(df$item, function(x) as.list(setNames(str_extract_all(x, "[0-9]+")[[1]], strsplit(x, "[0-9]+")[[1]]))),
    fill = TRUE
  )
)

   id apple milk juice  egg
1:  1     2    5  <NA> <NA>
2:  2  <NA>    1  <NA> <NA>
3:  3     5 <NA>     3 <NA>
4:  4  <NA> <NA>     1   10
5:  5  <NA>    2  <NA>    8
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It's a nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner `data.table` solution with input from `stringr`:

```
df[, 
   .(it_count = str_extract_all(item, "[0-9]+")[[1]], 
     it_name = str_extract_all(item, "[^0-9]+")[[1]]), 
   by = id
   ][, dcast(.SD, id ~ it_name, value.var = "it_count")]

   id apple  egg juice milk
1:  1     2 <NA>  <NA>    5
2:  2  <NA> <NA>  <NA>    1
3:  3     5 <NA>     3 <NA>
4:  4  <NA>   10     1 <NA>
5:  5  <NA>    8  <NA>    2
```